# Select image from gridview and display it on other intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I am creating Gallery.
I have gridlayout which display all images.
Now i want to do that when we select one image then another intent will start that i have done,but now i want to display that selected image in this new intent.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Use below code of gridview.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(Constants.mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Constants.java

```
public class Constants {
    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intentt mInDisplay=new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                mInDisplay.putExtra("Index", position);
                startActivity(mInDisplay);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mImgView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

DisplayActivity.java

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Bundle bdl=getIntent().getExtras();
        int index=bdl.getInt("Index");      
        ImageView mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgView1);
        mImage.setImageResource(Constants.mThumbIds[index]);
    }
}
```

And Declare both activities into your android manifest file.

Comment: This work great.but after 4 show it generate error,logcat say 07-17 17:37:24.399: E/AndroidRuntime(881): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Comment: @vinay Finish first activity when open second activity and finish second activity when open first activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a click listener on every image via [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29), the listener can then send the intent to start the new activity.

We also want to send the image path with the intent. To achieve this you can use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) 
 on your intent with a name you choose as first parameter and the image path as second parameter.

You should then be able to retrive the image path by using [getStringExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) in your new activity. You will need to get the intent by calling getIntent() in your activity

Good luck