# Error when "Select image from gridview and display it on other intent"

Tags: android

I am trying to select image from gridview and display it on other intent.
I saw this solution : [Select image from gridview and display it on other intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518851/select-image-from-gridview-and-display-it-on-other-intent)

But I have an error, using the debugger I was able to find that my appli/program quit a this line :

mImage.setImageResource(Constants.mThumbIds[index]);

I checked index's number is good.

My code :
DisplayActivity.java :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bdl=getIntent().getExtras();
    int index=bdl.getInt("Index");      
    ImageView mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgView1);
    int test = Constante.mThumbIds[index];

    mImage.setImageResource(Constante.mThumbIds[index]);

    setContentView(R.layout.display);
}
```

Constante.java

```
public class Constante {
// references to our images
public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {
     R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
     R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
     R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
     R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
     R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
     R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
     R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
     R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
     R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
     R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
     R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};}
```

Comment: are you getting a force close? if so post the exception

Comment: My application crashed, but now it is fixed with the solution of wang.
Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ImageView may be null. Try to put setContextView right after super method.